# NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest issue

Tags: ios, swift, nsurlconnection, nsurlrequest, facebook-sdk-3.1

I'm sorry the title is not clearer, but it's hard to resume the problem in one sentence.

I'm using the Facebook SDK to retrieve user information. My intent is to instantiate a class I wrote myself called Profile, which contains several user information, including the binary for the avatar picture (`NSData`).

To do this, I first use `FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath` and then, in the completion handler, I create a Profile instance and request the avatar binary data, using `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:`

As soon as I get the complete profile, I notify a delegate with `didReceiveProfile:`. Now, the delegate is `LoginViewController`, which is a subclass of `UIViewController`. This method then saves the profile data to disk and then does this:

```
var app: UIApplication = UIApplication.sharedApplication();
var delegate: AppDelegate = app.delegate as AppDelegate;

delegate.application(app, didReceiveProfile: profile);
```

So the idea is to notify the `AppDelegate` that a Profile is now available, so whatever view controller that follows `LoginViewController` can now be displayed. Here's the code for that:

```
var storyboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: MainStoryboardIdentifier, bundle: nil);
var profileVC: ProfileViewController! = storyboard.instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier(ProfileViewControllerIdentifier) as ProfileViewController;

NSLog("Everything OK");

self.navigationController!.pushViewController(profileVC, animated: false);
```

I do get the log "Everything OK", but the view doesn't show.

A few more details.

When the application first loads, it checks whether the profile has been saved to disk. If it has, it loads the profile from the file and calls `didReceiveProfile:` which instantly jumps to the second screen. So, the same method is called and it works. It can't be the code.

Also, notice that `NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest:queue:completionHandler:` is called inside the `FBRequestConnection.startWithGraphPath`'s completion handler. If I call the delegate's `didReceiveProfile:` method *before* `sendAsynchronousRequest` (that is, in Facebook's completion handler), then it works and the view is properly shown, but I do not have the avatar binary. But if I call it inside `sendAsynchronousRequest`'s completion handler, then the view doesn't show. It just gets back to the login view.

I am new to iOS development, but by my experience it seems like the completion handler is being called in a different thread? Being asynchronous and all.

So, how do I get the view to show?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I realised I left out something really important. As soon as I did, I also realised what the problem was. I was calling `sendAsynchronousRequest` like this:

```
var request = NSURLRequest(URL: url);
let queue = NSOperationQueue();
NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: queue, completionHandler:{ /* RESPONSE CODE */ });
```

Obviously the queue is not right. It should be:

```
let queue = NSOperationQueue.mainQueue();
```

That solved it.